# Modern Conveniences in a dystopian anarchy

Tags: society, government, post-apocalypse, dystopia, infrastructure

So for a story which I am writing, I want to have modern conveniences and utilities in place (e.g. Youtube, Amazon, stores, things of that nature). However, it is a post apocalyptic world with no system of government, roaming bands of raiders, things like that. Obviously, there are things like attacks on stores, power lines being cut, and I have taken that into consideration. My real question is how this sort of collapse could have happened in the first place, and how these utilities could be maintained without some sort of order being restored. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Edit- Thanks for the feedback, new to world-building.

1. I have many of the main ideas, scenarios, etc. for my story. What I want is simply the causation for the world it takes place in.
2. The one question that I'm asking- What political situation and social breakdown can cause this?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! At the moment you seem to be asking us to write your story for you. That is not the purpose of this site. Maybe you can rewrite your question (?)

Comment: You could have a region of the world where no government etc. exists, but other parts where everything is fine and the big internet companies are. Or you could have the big companies in space-stations around the world, providing wireless internet everywhere, but on earth itself nearly everything is collapsed.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  Our [help/on-topic] states, "the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story."  Worlbuilding is about rules & systems. Storybuilding is about circumstances, actions, and plot.  Learn more reading about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868).

Comment: @JulianEgner -- in other words, just like the real world?

Comment: Hi Franklin! You're asking too many questions! Please pare down to one focused question that can be answered with one on point answer.

Comment: @user535733, sure there's furniture!  There's the card table your computer is on and the folding chair you're chains are welded to.  Oh, and the hook on the wall where your supervisor hangs his whip - just out of your reach.

Comment: @elemtilas unfortunately, you are right. While I wrote the comment, I had this strong feeling that our world could be like this.

Answer (score 1):

Inidividuals will band together and run services and businesses on a case by case basis.

[**Anarcho-communism.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-communism)

> Anarcho-communism... is a political philosophy and anarchist school of
>   thought which advocates the abolition of the state, capitalism, wage
>   labour and private property (while retaining respect for personal
>   property, along with collectively-owned items, goods and services) in
>   favor of common ownership of the means of production, direct democracy
>   (among communes, participatory democracy), cooperativism, equal
>   distribution of valuables, and a horizontal network of workers'
>   councils with production and consumption based on the guiding
>   principle: "From each according to his ability, to each according to
>   his needs".

Without a state or central government to oversee, individuals group together and work together to preserve and maintain what they value.  In essence, everything is a cooperative.   Public services can work this way - the National Guard of the US is composed entirely of volunteers, and fire departments and ambulance services are run by volunteers in some places.  The police force of your world can be a combination of volunteers and prior officers who organize themselves and are supported by the communities they protect.

Your stores and services the survive do so because they are valued by individuals, who group together to keep these things going.  The anarchic aspect means that each business entity and service that survives the apocalypse might have a different story behind how it survived - one might have been taken over by the workers who run it, one might have been resuscitated by customers who miss it, one might be claimed by a religious organization, and so on.

Some of these things will have the same name, but be very different from how they were before the fall.  It will be fun to write and fun to read!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I really like the idea of the stories behind each business.

Comment: Don't forget that there is also an [anarcho-capitalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-capitalism). Communists do not have a monopoly on crazy.